# Direct URL to OneDrive and Outlook login pages without going through home page

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I have a basic application with icons that redirect users to different Microsoft applications via specific hardcoded URLs. When I click on icons for `OneDrive` or `Outlook`, it currently takes me to the respective home pages, where I then have to click on `Sign In` to access the login page.

I'm looking for direct URLs that can route me directly to the login pages of OneDrive and Outlook without having to interact with the home page at all.

Here are the URLs I'm currently using:

```
{
  name: "OneDrive",
  url: "https://onedrive.live.com"
},
{
  name: "Outlook",
  url: "https://outlook.live.com"
}
```

Is there a way or specific URL structure that I can use to bypass the OneDrive and Outlook home pages and directly access their login pages?

I have tried to register the application as an admin, but it's still not working as expected. Additionally, if I force it to open the login page every time, then it will take the user to the login page without considering if the user is already logged in or not.

This is necessary for a specific use case, and any suggestions or insights on achieving this would be nice.